# Вывод тегов в виде тега, а не текста

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В переменную `Vue` записан тег (переменная `SomeTag` и тег `<a href="test">топ ссылка</a>`).
При выводе `<div>{{SomeTag}}</div>` выводит: `<a href="test">топ ссылка</a>`, а мне нужно чтобы выводило: `топ ссылка`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вывода html-кода можно использовать директиву [`v-html`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#%D0%A1%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-HTML), но **важно** следить за тем, что таким образом выводится, т. к. это является уязвимостью и опасно для неконтролируемых данных (может быть выполнен, например, *js код*).

Пример:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    html: '<strong>Hi!</strong>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  HTML: <span v-html='html'></span>
</div>
```